What is a Locus?
I am having trouble with what a Locus is and the idea of it. I have a Locus problem and I think I understand how to solve it but I just don't understand the concept and what it is.
2a. Consider two points $A(2, -1)$ and $B(5, 2)$. Find the equation of the locus of a point $P$ such that $PA=PB$.

You want all possible locations of such points $P$.

Typically, they are after a description, in this case a Geometric description, of the solution set.  Such as "the unit circle centered at the origin" (though that's obviously not the correct answer in this case).  You say you think you know the answer..why not edit your post to add that?

@TedShifrin This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

Point well taken, @Martin. These days I rarely post answers because often the “low quality question” police punish me; this was one of those cases. Can’t one just google the word locus or — my gosh — look it up in a dictionary?

@Martin: Already one downvote. Told you so. This place has become a miserable joke.

Yeah, true  $~$

The locus of points $P$ satisfying a certain condition is just the set of all such possible points $P$. The word is the Latin word for place (think location). You can typically give a geometric description, although in this case they want an actual (algebraic) equation.

In German, the locus is called "location curve" which I find more descriptive :)

It's the set of all points that satisfy the equation (make it a true statement).  In this case, for 2a, find the midpoint between Point A and Point B (3.5, .5).  The locus is the line passing through the midpoint that is perpendicular to $\overline{\text{AB}}$.  The slope of $\overline{\text{AB}}$ is $\tfrac{2-(-1)}{5-2} = \tfrac{3}{3} = 1$, so the slope of the perpendicular line is -1.  Then use the point-slope form $y=m(x-x_1)+y_1$: $y=-1(x-3.5)+.5 = -x+3.5+.5$.  So the equation of that line is $y = -x+4$.
